# Why does the whole page push itself up a few pixels when I am tabbing through the page?

Tags: html, css, angular, keyboard, accessibility

I am implementing a feature on a web page which allows the user to navigate using the tab key.

When I am tabbing through the page, eventually the page will have to automatically scroll down to tab to the new content. When this happens, the entire page moves itself up a few pixels, this is proven by the navigation bar disappearing from the top of the page. (stays in the DOM, just out of view).

Demo:

[image: Demo: The navigation bar disappears when tabbing]

Code:

*app.component.html*:

```
<div *ngIf="token" class="route-container">
  <app-search [token]="token"></app-search>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

*app.component.scss*:

```
.route-container {
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
app-search{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

*search.component.html*:

```
<nav class="navHeader">
    ...
</nav>
```

*search.component.scss*:

```
.navHeader {
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #808080;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Other information:

- Angular 8 (8.0.2)
- Tested this in 3 browsers (Edge, IE11, Chrome). The bug appears in all 3.

**EDIT**

After trying @Eliseo 's solution I changed the title of the question from *'why is the navigation moving'* to *'Why does the whole page push itself'* as I realised that it isn't just the menu being pushed up a few pixels.

Thanks

Comment: Is the navigation bar hidden/revealed on scroll? I already saw some bad implementations of this where the navbar is taken out of the page flow on scroll, which results in the page jumping up by the height of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

are you asking about?

```
.navHeader {
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

Comment: After trying this I have realised that it's not just the menu that's being pushed up, it's the entire page. I have updated the question.